# processing return from ajax call

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using the twitter-bootstrap's typeahead to do autocompletion on an input field.

What I have so far:

```
$(".airportSearch").typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url_,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                n: 12,
                q: typeahead
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var return_list = [], i = data.length;
                while(i--) {
                    return_list[i] = {
                        type: data[i].type,
                        id: data[i].iata,
                        value: data[i].city,
                        returnvalue: data[i].type == 'city' ? data[i].city + ' [' + data[i].iata + ']' :
                            data[i].city + ' (' + data[i].iata + ')'
                    };
                }

            }
        });
    }
});
```

example of output:

```
[{"type":"airport","city":"Quebec","airport":"Quebec","iata":"YQB","country":"Canada","locationId":"airport_YQB"},
{"type":"airport","city":"Queenstown","airport":"Queenstown","iata":"ZQN","country":"New Zealand","locationId":"airport_ZQN"},
{"type":"city","city":"Setif","airport":"All Airports","iata":"QSF","country":"Algeria","locationId":"DZ_city_QSF"},
{"type":"airport","city":"Setif","airport":"Setif","iata":"QSF","country":"Algeria","locationId":"airport_QSF"},
{"type":"airport","city":"QachaS Nek","airport":"QachaS Nek","iata":"UNE","country":"Lesotho","locationId":"airport_UNE"},
{"type":"airport","city":"Qaisumah","airport":"Qaisumah","iata":"AQI","country":"Saudi Arabia","locationId":"airport_AQI"}]
```

I have logged the return_list variable that I create and have confirmed that it is the expected list of objects I have created. I want to populate the autocomplete options with the returnvalue strings in the list of objects.

Could anyone tell me how, or point me to somewhere that tells me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".airportSearch").typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, process) {
        return $.ajax({ // return ajax result
            url: url_,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                n: 12,
                q: typeahead
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var return_list = [], i = data.length, data_vals = []; // add data_vals array for typeahead
                while(i--) {
                    return_list[i] = {
                        type: data[i].type,
                        id: data[i].iata,
                        value: data[i].city,
                        returnvalue: data[i].type == 'city' ? data[i].city + ' [' + data[i].iata + ']' :
                            data[i].city + ' (' + data[i].iata + ')'
                    };

                    data_vals.push(return_list[i].returnvalue); // populate the needed values
                }
                return process(data_vals); // and return to typeahead
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Normally I would populate the `data_vals` for typeahead only but you did it your way for your reason I guess.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Hieu, I'm not exactly sure how the ajax call works(have not found a good explanation online) so I'm not exactly sure what is happening.

Would this handle the data returned by the call?(I have included an example in the OP)

Also, I assume you meant "return query(data_vals);" and not "return process(data_vals);", because when I use "process" the console logs "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined"

Comment: ah right, I didn't notice you use different params for `source` callback. Normally I would use `source: function (query, process) {`. And yes it is handle the response of the AJAX call.